# How to get Android App id or name using PHP, Jquery or any API?

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working mobile responsibility website. I am using own app for show my website.

how to check user open website Using my app or other app (Like : chrome , firefox).

Comment: Send a custom user agent (or any other header) using your app.

Comment: I don't know android generate app using online app creator websites.

Comment: Me neither, but then you should update your tags with `android` or equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you might want to detect the user agent by ducktyping for web browser detection. This can be done using Javascript.

**Update :**

```
var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
    // Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   
    // Firefox 1.0+
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;              // Chrome 1+
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;   // At least IE6

var output;
output += 'isFirefox: ' + isFirefox + '\n';
output += 'isChrome: ' + isChrome + '\n';
output += 'isSafari: ' + isSafari + '\n';
output += 'isOpera: ' + isOpera + '\n';
output += 'isIE: ' + isIE + '\n';
console.log(output);
```

Here is the [reference link of the answer provided by Rob W.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Comment: Trying Useragent but it returns `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36`

Comment: Ok. Updating the answer. You might want look for ducktyping for web browser detection.